# Inheritance with Object.create() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was experimenting with Object.create() way of inheritance in Javascript.

While I clearly understand that this is how the inheritance is achieved using Object.create().

```
//Inheritance with Object.create()

function superClass(){
    this.name = "I'm a name in superclass";
  this.name2 = "Someone please pickup the phone.";
}

superClass.prototype.useMe = function(){
    this.name3 = "I'm name3";
  this.name4 = "I'm name4";
}

function subClass() {
    superClass.call(this);
}
subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);
subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
var obj = new subClass();

console.log(obj.constructor);

Output:
function subClass() {
    superClass.call(this);
}
```

The confusion arose when I moved the positioning of these two lines,

```
subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);
subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
```

See below,

```
//Inheritance with Object.create()

function superClass(){
    this.name = "I'm a name in superclass";
  this.name2 = "Someone please pickup the phone.";
}

superClass.prototype.useMe = function(){
    this.name3 = "I'm name3";
  this.name4 = "I'm name4";
}

function subClass() {
    superClass.call(this);
}

var obj = new subClass();
subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);
//I've commented the constructor assignment. 
//subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;

console.log(obj.constructor);

Output:
function subClass() {
    superClass.call(this);
}
```

Isn't this suppose to return the constructor function as superClass as I commented the constructor assignment line.

Now, the question is; Is the positioning of `subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);` is really important?

Case 1: When I placed it above the object creation line, the assignment of new constructor function was required.

Case 2: When I placed it below the object creation line, I don't think we need the constructor assignment line, as it's clearly referencing the proper constructor function.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: I'm not mixing Object.create with constructor function. 
My only confusion was; when I placed the line `subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass);` after the object creation, it should change the `subClass.prototype.constructor` to `superClass`'s constructor. But it didn't it is taking the subClass's constructor. How? Or, am I missing something here.

Comment: I think a lot of this code is unnecessary? `var subClass = Object.create(superClass)`. If you are mixing `Object.create` with constructors, you are missing the point.

Comment: Yes, it's important. If you're going to set the `.prototype` of your constructor function, do it *before* you construct any instances. If you don't, those instances will not use the new prototype.

Comment: Per your edit, you are calling `new subClass`. You are __absolutely__ using constructor functions.